# MS Access table field validation rule for only 5 letters and 5 numbers?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

What format can be used as field validation rule that user must enter 5 letters first and then 5 numbers? is it possible without codes??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with an InputMask:

```
LLLLL00000
```

If you do not want to use the InputMask, you could write the validation rule like this:

```
Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"
```

References:

- [Characters For Input Masks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-e125997a-7791-49e5-8672-4a47832de8da#__toc292266517)
- [Validation Rules](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/access-validation-rule-tutorial/list-of-access-validation-rules)

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime if it should be in uppercase?

Comment: I mean it should appear in uppercase even if user enters in lowercase

Comment: You can use the Format ">" to display all caps. It won't change the underlying data, but it will display it with the format.

Comment: Thats great. Just one simple thing. In one field i need user to enter below format repeatedly many times and each set should be separated by / (slash).Example (QR123456/QR442536) 

Like "[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

Comment: Just duplicate your rule with slashes between them.